# removing empty lines from a string c++

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to remove the empty lines created when I remove a person from list in a file so my file looks much nicer when is open. this is Code i have to remove the line.

```
std::ifstream ifs("alpha.dat");



  std::ofstream tem("temporary.text");

std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());



cout << str;
tem << str;
tem.close();    
ifs.close();
```

my file content is the following:

```
maria hernandez 1000 h3777 +1000 19:15:19    
rachel dominguez 100000 X8793 +100000 19:15:20                                                  
carlos yatch 20 g6386 +20 19:15:20 

Empty line

carlos Domingues 20 g3336 +20 19:15:20                                                                                                                
Empty Line
```

but What I'm getting on the file is the current:

```
maria hernandez 1000 h3777 +1000 19:15:19 rachel dominguez 100000 X8793 +100000 19:15:20 carlos yatch 20 g6386 +20 19:15:20
```

Comment: `'\n` isn't a blank line. It's just the end of the line. Think about what character patterns a blank line has.

Comment: I was wondering about that due. I mean white lines can contain space but my lines don't really contain anything ..

Comment: @Cris Just look at something like "Hello\nWorld" it goes over 2 lines but there isn't a blank line. On the other hand if you got "Hello\n\nWorld" You got a single blank line. Hope that helps you understand your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't just remove all `\n`'s. They don't represent blank lines, rather the start of a **newline**. You got a blank line when you got more than one consecutive `\n`.

For removing these consecutive `\n` characters I'd suggest replacing:

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());
```

with something like this:

```
str.erase(std::unique(str.begin(), str.end(),
                      [] (char a, char b) {return a == '\n' && b == '\n';}),
          str.end());
```

Working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/013ec1bdf3d2c9d9).

`std::unique` removes equal consecutive elements. But since we only want to remove newlines we pass a lambda as predicate. As last we only need to erase the duplicate `\n` that were moved to the end of the container.

Comment: I try using your code along with my compiler but it seems that i get an error trying to use the code.

Comment: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]

error: no matching function for call to 'unique(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, CountLines()::<lambda(char, char)>)'

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'unique(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, CountLines()::<lambda(char, char)>)'

warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]

Comment: `lamba` is the new multithreading we were all hearing about a few years back

Comment: @Cris `no matching function for call to 'unique'...` You got <algortihm> included? I was assuming you got that included since you use `std::remove` in your code.

Comment: @Cris Also the warning concerning lambda is becaus they got added with the C++11 standard. You probably should use `-std=c++11` compiler flag so you don't get warnings for all the new c++11 goodies.

Comment: @SeanPedersen not multithreading, lambda functions are [Anonymous Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) that got added with c++11.

Comment: Awesome. Now I need to buy a new book. :/

Comment: That is interesting... i just read about it never heard of "lamba" it seems to be an error with the compiler library ..

Answer (score 0):

To remove blank lines, you need to make sure you are removing redundant `\r` by turning them all into `\n`, while making sure you don't accidentally add lines (`{'\r', '\n'}`), then it's a simple task of removing duplicates.

Comment: What does `\r` have to do with his question? I can't see anything about them there. If you're refering to different OS's representing a newline as `\r\n`, `\n` or `r`, remember that they all get turned into `\n` already when you read it as input.

Comment: How fascinating. C++ has yet to cease amazing me.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the carriage return occurring twice, and remove one.

```
size_t pos;
while ((pos= str.find("\n\n", 0)) != std::string::npos)
{
    str.erase(pos, 1);
}
```

Run it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/784a83a1e1fdad0a)

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Processing of text lines the method length()
 The search for the longest line of the text.
 Removing of the particular line of text.
The first step.
 Write a function to find the empty line of the text file:*/
//------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int Find();
void Remove( int k);
//------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
 cout << "blank line no "<<"is:   "<<Find()<<endl;
 Remove(Find());
 return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------
int Find()
{
 int nr = 0; string ilg = "";
 int n = 0; string eil;
 ifstream fd("Data.txt");
 while (!fd.eof()) {
 getline(fd, eil);
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {  
 if (eil.length() == 0) {
     nr = n; ilg = eil;}
 }
 n++;

 }
  fd.close();
 return nr;
}
//---------------------
/*The second step. Write a function to remove the given line:*/
//------------------------------------------------------------
void Remove( int k)
{
 string eil;
 ofstream fr("Result.txt");
 ifstream fd("Data.txt");
 // The lines are copied till the removed
 for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
 getline(fd, eil);
 fr << eil << endl;
 }
 // The line, which has to be removed, is not copied
 getline(fd, eil);
 // The remaining lines are copied
 while (!fd.eof()) {
 getline(fd, eil);
 fr << eil << endl;
 }
 fd.close();
 fr.close();
}
//---
```

Comment: This can remove only first blank line..I do not know how to remove all blank lines by slightly change in the code....